# incomprehensible C macro

Tags: c, macros

I bumped into the following macro while analyzing a code.

```
#define __COMMAND_HANDLER(name, extra ...) int name(struct command_invocation *cmd, ## extra)
```

The function `name` is passed as an argument to `__COMMAND_HANDLER` however there is no definition of this function anywhere else in the code. The cmd argument's type (`command_invocation`) is defined. Basically I couldn't understand the functionality of this macro because I couldn't find the definition of the function `name`. Is name some kind of pre-defined function in standard C library ? Does this macro definition make sense if `name` is not defined ?

Comment: Note that the macro definition is not standard C; it is using a GNU extension.  There'd be a comma before the triple dots if it was a standard macro.  Also, names starting with double underscore (or underscore and a capital letter) are reserved for use by 'the implementation'.  You shouldn't define a macro like that in your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Durning preprocession, the preprocessor will replace all occurrences of `__COMMAND_HANDLER(name, extra ...)` macro to its body with replacing each occurences of `name` and `extra...` inside its body to the tokens you specified.

This means in this case that whatever you enter for `name` argument, it will be a function name, and `extra...` will be its additional parameters beside the first one (`struct command_invocation *cmd`).

For example the following line:

```
__COMMAND_HANDLER(foo, int param) {
    /* definition */
}
```

after preprocessing will be:

```
int foo(struct command_invocation *cmd, int param) {
    /* definition */
}
```

One important thing has to be clarified: the `##` before `extra` and named variable argument (using `extra...` instead of `...`) are not the part of the [c](/questions/tagged/c) standard but they are [GNU extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html). The effect of `##` after comma lets you specify nothing for variable argument. Compiling your example with GCC (with `-pedantic` flag) when it's used as follows, you will see warning messages:

```
/* The following example will print the following messages:
 * warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros [-Wvariadic-macros]
 * warning: ISO C99 requires at least one argument for the "..." in a variadic
 * macro
 */
__COMMAND_HANDLER(bar);
```

Normally the `##` is the operator for token concatenation, i.e. two tokens on either side of a `##` operator are combined into a single one. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FOO(name, number) void name##number()

FOO(bar, 1) { puts("I'm first."); }
FOO(bar, 2) { puts("I'm second."); }

int main() {
    bar1();
    bar2();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a macro and name is a parameter.
You use it like this:

```
__COMMAND_HANDLER(hello, char* world)
```

During pre-process stage, it would transform your code into:

```
int hello(struct command_invocation *cmd, char *world);
```

In this case, name is passed as hello, and extra = char* world.
If you don't pass anything for extra, ## will discard the comma.

Comment: Please elaborate the effect of the `...` in combination with the `##`.

Answer (score 0):

In short: the macro is creating the function with the name specified by the parameter `name` and optional additional arguments specified by `extra ...`.

Note: names starting with a double underscore is implementation reserved and shouldn't be used.

The macro is variadic.

The second argument to the macro `extra ...` provides a name to use instead of the default `__VA_ARGS__` inside the function declaration macro. This is a GNU extension

`## extra` is another GNU extension that specifies to the preprocessor that if the second argument to the macro `__COMMAND_HANDLER` is omitted, the preceding comma can be removed and the function called without it.

The reason you can't find the declaration of `name` is because it's a parameter to your macro! The macro itself is declaring a new function with whatever is in name, and the arguments provided, with the default first argument of `struct command_invocation *cmd`.

Here are some examples:

Calling:
`__COMMAND_HANDLER(cmd,char * w)`
Would result in the function declaration of:
`int cmd(struct command_invocation *cmd,char * w)`

Whereas calling:
`__COMMAND_HANDLER(cmd2)`
would result in the function declaration of:
`int cmd2(struct command_invocation *cmd)`